# О синтаксически нечленимых сочетаниях

Tags: синтаксис

В Статье на сайте "1 сентября" http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200302310 читаю:

На слете удалось побеседовать со многими школьниками (со многими школьниками – дополнение при сказуемом удалось побеседовать, многими – определение при этом дополнении);

Перед многими школами посадили деревья (перед школами – обстоятельство при сказуемом посадили, многими – определение при этом обстоятельстве).

По-моему, со многими школьниками - это членимое сочетание: со школьниками - дополнение, так же как и во втором предложении, где дополнение - перед школами, а не перед многими школами.

Answer (score 1):

15) На слете удалось побеседовать со многими школьниками (со МНОГИМИ школьниками – дополнение при сказуемом удалось побеседовать, многими – определение при этом дополнении); 16) Перед многими школами посадили деревья (перед школами – обстоятельство при сказуемом посадили, многими – определение при этом обстоятельстве). 
      - ЭТО ПРОСТО ОПЕЧАТКА. Конечно же, в этих предложениях "многими" - определение.

Comment: спасибо. теперь понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, элементарная опечатка. Ну там даже по смыслу не получается.

со *многими* школьниками – дополнение при сказуемом удалось побеседовать, *многими* – определение при этом дополнении;
(курсив мой, b-s)
Многими - определение при дополнении, частью которого оно является?! 
Членимость-нечленимость здесь вообще не имеет отношения, если не опечатка, то придется признать, что у автора что-то не в порядке с логикой..

ЗЫ Вы бы сформулировали ясно мысль, которую хотите опровергнуть или обсудить. Потому как сразу и не видно, кто и о чем тут спорит...

ЗЗЫ Не видел предыдущего ответа. Но меня больше интересует, как удалось дать его дважды...

Comment: Да, извините. Мне надо было сформулировать вопрос иначе.

Comment: Да не стоит извиняться, это не претензия, это совет.